# как в layout выводить несколько представлений

Tags: c#, asp.net, layout

в самом layout хранится список ссылок на страницы на сайте
название страниц подтягивается из БД,
чтоб layout оставался статичным, хочу в нем подгружать дополнительное представление, внутри которого выводить список доступных ссылок

пока что элементы списка выводятся через компонент, но он статичный. Чтоб воспользоваться перегрузкой вызова компонента и передать ему модель, сама модель должна уже быть на layout'е.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]